# Need to add view list anchor tag for another model in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a two models question and answers. I am now able to show both the models in django admin. But i need to show a link for  View Answers  in question listing page in django admin. And this link should only show the answers of related question.

For example

Question  Date     ViewAnswers
A             21.2.12 View Answers
B             22.2.12 View Answers

Answer model have foreign key of question in it.
And i want by clicking the view answers link i am able to see listing of all the answers for that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your app is called `app` and question field of the `Answer` model is named `question` :-)

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['question', 'date', 'view_answers']

    def view_answers(self, obj):
        url = reverse("admin:app_answer_changelist")
        return '<a href="%s?question=%d">View answers</a>' % (url, obj.pk)
    view_answers.short_description = 'View answers'
    view_answers.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Look at the first line of my code.  There is an import of `reverse`.

Comment: Sorry for that. You are awesome thanks for your instant response :)